# Selecting vertex with mouse JOGL

Tags: opengl, mouse, jogl

I use JOGL and trying to make sure that when you click on the vertex this vertex has been selected. I'm trying to pick the top in color, but do not understand how to get the color under the cursor. I found this [glReadPixels in mousePressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329663/glreadpixels-in-mousepressed), but it only works in GLEventListener's thread. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you post the most relavant portions of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this answer is too late, but i will post it. I am not sure your purpose, in case you want to pick the object in the scence why don't you use the OpenGl selection. You can find the tutorial [here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html) and a demo video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJJQ-7R7w_s) (from a hip hop guy ;) i think)

Answer (score 1):

> I use JOGL and trying to make sure that when you click on the vertex **this vertex has been selected.**

OpenGL doesn't work like this. It draws something, then it forgets about it. The picture you see on the screen is just that: A picture. One something has been drawn, OpenGL has no kind of recollection, what it was it actually drew.

You want to select vertices? Well, then you've to back project a ray into the scene *you* maintain in a data structure *you* must write, to test which vertex is closest to that ray.